# downgrade from ubuntu 23.10 to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, downgrade, 23.10

my problem is that I need to be on ubuntu 22.04 but currently I am in 23.10. Unfortunately I am a new linux user so i don't know how to properly use the O.S. there is a way to downgrade to that version?

thank you.

Comment: There really isn't a way to truly downgrade the OS.  It is better if you reinstall the older version.

Comment: What is the reason for needing 22,04 ?

Comment: you should clone your drive to backup before you upgrade or update

Comment: The best way is to implement your backup plan (ie. restore from your backups your prior release), as Ubuntu tools are intended to upgrade you to newer releases, and not go backwards. I've providing a re-install method; though as there are more complications in going backwards (*which are package/app specific and not release specific; I've written about some of those problems on other answers multiple times*) you need to do your homework first if data matters to you. Whilst I've seldom had issues going backwards, and never lost data, I was without it awhile as outlined due to GNOME app changes

Comment: I need it to use a framework for the development of a racing car without the driver but with an AI that recognise the track...thank you for your help

Comment: There are no *magical* answers; the *downgrade* tag if you re-read it, refers to downgrading packages. To *downgrade* your whole system you need to repeat that for almost all packages you have installed, and there are no tools that do that automatically (*intentionally; ie. for reasons*) as backups provide that feature OR you re-install as already stated.